# Detecting Hybrid Devices

Tags: javascript, modernizr, feature-detection

What is the recommended way to detect and bind events for **hybrid devices** that support both mouse and touch?

For example, if Modernizr had a test called `hybrid`, you might do something like this:

```
var handler = null;

switch (true) {
  case (Modernizr.hybrid):
    handler = 'touchstart click';
    break;
  case (Modernizr.touch):
    handler = 'touchstart';
    break;
  default:
    handler = 'click';
    break;
}
```

Comment: just bind touchstart along with click each time, it won't hurt anything if the event doesn't fire...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @dandavis said in his comment, bind them all.

You can be a bit intelligent about it though: although you don't know whether the user will want to use touch or mouse (or keyboard or a some other input device), you can detect the different event models (pointer / touch) — and hence only bind events which *might* fire.

Every input device can fire `click` events though, so make sure you always bind them and you're covered:

```
if ('onpointerdown' in window) {
    // Bind to Pointer Events: `pointerdown`, `pointerup`, etc
}
else {
    // Bind to mouse events: `mousedown`, `mouseup`, etc

    if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
        // Bind to Touch Events: `touchstart`, `touchend`, etc
    }
}
// Bind to keyboard events: `keydown`, `keyup`, etc if
// necessary; can be problematic though
// Always bind to `click` events
```

More detail: http://www.stucox.com/blog/the-golden-pattern-for-handling-touch-input/

Comment: What about `tap` events? I need to bind them as well as `touchstart` so I can ignore long taps and handle swipes etc. Binding to click events in addition to these events is causing callbacks to be executed twice.

Comment: @AdamFraser – `tap` isn’t a standard DOM event… are you using a library, maybe [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)? If so, I’d recommend *just* using Hammer’s event model and not mixing it with standard touch events (certainly not on the same element) – you can probably do everything you need with Hammer alone.

Comment: Oh, re. firing twice with `click` – make sure your handlers call `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @StuCox Ah! Thanks, it looks like we actually are using Hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [you can't detect a touchscreen](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/), and therefore, you can't detect a hybriddevice.

For what its worth, based on your sample code, `click` will fire for all of those events. 
If you give more information as to what you are trying to accomplish, I could suggest more possibilities.